# ActionBar with Search and One more option

Tags: android-actionbar, android-menu

I would like to add 2 menu options to the action bar. One is Search and the other is custom one. When I tried to add, the 2nd option is always going to over flow menu only. But I want that to be displayed always as below.

[image]

But it's being displayed as

[image]

Here is my menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_new_event"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_add_new_event"/>

</menu>
```

Any idea about how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the below code

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_new_event"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_add_new_event"/>
```

to

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_new_event"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        yourapp:showAsAction**="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_add_new_event"/>
```

and it worked.